# Decimal error in brain tree dashboard

Tags: braintree, braintree-sandbox

When I am making transaction through **braintree**  payment gateway I get the response which I have attached below the amount returned is 1200 but in the braintree dashboard I get 1.200 (decimal).

```
"PAYMENT": {
        "transaction": {
            "id": "dhsaj2vy",
            "status": "submitted_for_settlement",
            "type": "sale",
            "currencyIsoCode": "EUR",
            "amount": "1200.00",
            "merchantAccountId": "5646466767909",
            "subMerchantAccountId": null,
            "masterMerchantAccountId": null,
            "orderId": null,
            "createdAt": "2017-08-19T13:05:47Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-08-19T13:05:47Z",
            "customer": {
                "id": "8239041739880",
                "firstName": "a@g.com",
                "lastName": "",
                "company": null,
                "email": null,
                "website": null,
                "phone": null,
                "fax": null
            },
            "billing": {
                "id": "ff",
                "firstName": null,
                "lastName": null,
                "company": null,
                "streetAddress": null,
                "extendedAddress": null,
                "locality": null,
                "region": null,
                "postalCode": "5328",
                "countryName": null,
                "countryCodeAlpha2": null,
                "countryCodeAlpha3": null,
                "countryCodeNumeric": null
            },
            "refundId": null,
            "refundIds": [],
            "refundedTransactionId": null,
            "partialSettlementTransactionIds": [],
            "authorizedTransactionId": null,
            "settlementBatchId": null,
            "shipping": {
                "id": null,
                "firstName": null,
                "lastName": null,
                "company": null,
                "streetAddress": null,
                "extendedAddress": null,
                "locality": null,
                "region": null,
                "postalCode": null,
                "countryName": null,
                "countryCodeAlpha2": null,
                "countryCodeAlpha3": null,
                "countryCodeNumeric": null
            },
            "customFields": "",
            "avsErrorResponseCode": null,
            "avsPostalCodeResponseCode": "M",
            "avsStreetAddressResponseCode": "I",
            "cvvResponseCode": "I",
            "gatewayRejectionReason": null,
            "processorAuthorizationCode": "F6D7CV",
            "processorResponseCode": "1000",
            "processorResponseText": "Approved",
            "additionalProcessorResponse": null,
            "voiceReferralNumber": null,
            "purchaseOrderNumber": null,
            "taxAmount": null,
            "taxExempt": false,
            "creditCard": {
                "token": "6wh2v4",
                "bin": "555555",
                "last4": "4444",
                "cardType": "MasterCard",
                "expirationMonth": "12",
                "expirationYear": "2025",
                "customerLocation": "US",
                "cardholderName": null,
                "imageUrl": "https://assets.braintreegateway.com/payment_method_logo/mastercard.png?environment=sandbox",
                "prepaid": "Unknown",
                "healthcare": "Unknown",
                "debit": "Unknown",
                "durbinRegulated": "Unknown",
                "commercial": "Unknown",
                "payroll": "Unknown",
                "issuingBank": "Unknown",
                "countryOfIssuance": "Unknown",
                "productId": "Unknown",
                "uniqueNumberIdentifier": "4522ba536b44dec3d9d7a7cc3b059d1e",
                "venmoSdk": false,
                "maskedNumber": "555555******4444",
                "expirationDate": "12/2025"
            },
            "statusHistory": [{
                "timestamp": "2017-08-19T13:05:47Z",
                "status": "authorized",
                "amount": "12011.00",
                "user": "g5bareja@gmail.com",
                "transactionSource": "api"
            }, {
                "timestamp": "2017-08-19T13:05:47Z",
                "status": "submitted_for_settlement",
                "amount": "1200.00",
                "user": "g5bareja@gmail.com",
                "transactionSource": "api"
            }],
            "planId": null,
            "subscriptionId": null,
            "subscription": {
                "billingPeriodEndDate": null,
                "billingPeriodStartDate": null
            },
            "addOns": [],
            "discounts": [],
            "descriptor": {
                "name": null,
                "phone": null,
                "url": null
            },
            "recurring": false,
            "channel": null,
            "serviceFeeAmount": null,
            "escrowStatus": null,
            "disbursementDetails": {
                "disbursementDate": null,
                "settlementAmount": null,
                "settlementCurrencyIsoCode": null,
                "settlementCurrencyExchangeRate": null,
                "fundsHeld": null,
                "success": null
            },
            "disputes": [],
            "authorizationAdjustments": [],
            "paymentInstrumentType": "credit_card",
            "processorSettlementResponseCode": "",
            "processorSettlementResponseText": "",
            "threeDSecureInfo": null,
            "paypalAccount": {},
            "coinbaseAccount": {},
            "applePayCard": {}
        },
```

But in dashboard I see 1.200 why is there error in decimal points when braintree is returning me the correct amount?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

What you see in your Dashboard is the correct *format* of Euro currency denoting the value one thousand two hundred.

A quick search for proper formatting of Euro currency shows that the decimal separator is a "," and the thousands separator is a ".". Here's an example contrasting EUR and USD:

```
EUR 1.200,00
USD 1,200.00
```

Braintree adheres to the standard format of [the currencies it supports](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/currencies).